# How do I filter a group by checking if a value is present in the group in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a `journals` and `transactions` table. The `journals` is the parent and the `transactions` its child.

What I am trying to do is group the `transactions` table to check the `sum(amounts)`. But I don't need the whole `transactions` - only those where an `account` is present

I know this is an awful description, but I have no idea how to even approch this. so if you guys need more details please let me know.

basically, this is the query that I want to achieve. But its not working for some reason which i don't know.

```sql
select 
    t1.*
from 
    (
        select 
            journal_id,
            sum(amount)
            group_concat(quote(account)) as acc_codes 
        from
            `transactions` 
        group by journal_id 
    ) as t1
where '4500' in (t1.acc_codes)
```

Comment: try looking at t1 first then see if acc_codes is a list or not. good luck

Comment: "I know this is an awful description" -- Yes indeed... To improve, you should always provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ thanx maan I also learned a new thing. :)

Comment: @stickybit I will next time. Thats is why I described my query in sql. coz code speaks better for me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the subquery approach and instead add a `HAVING` clause assertion which checks for the presence of the account:

```sql
SELECT journal_id, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM `transactions` 
GROUP BY journal_id
HAVING SUM(account = '4500') > 0;
```

Comment: Ahh! I have also been trying to avoid subquery but as I said I didn't had any idea so to best convey what I want, I wrote the query. Thanks again maan. you are a life saver